# Dúvida com laço de repetição

Tags: php, loop, foreach

estou fazendo uma série de exercícios em PHP para prática. E me deparei com uma dúvida em relação a laço de repetição.
Para explicar melhor vou colocar o enunciado do exercício aqui:

```
Efetue um algorítmo PHP que receba dois valores quaisquer e efetue sua multiplicação utilizando para isso apenas o operador “+”, visto que:
(3 * 5) = 5 + 5 + 5
(4 * 12) = 12 + 12 + 12 + 12
```

No exercício o primeiro fator passado é o numero de vezes que o fator 2 terá que ser somado.
Pelo o que o exercício pede eu consegui realizar a soma, mas, eu queria também mostrar os valores somados na tela, por exemplo, 5+5+5+5 = 20.

Para este exercício eu utilizei array. Segue meu código:

```
<?php

$fator1 = isset($_POST['fator1']) ? $_POST['fator1']: '';
$fator2 = isset($_POST['fator2']) ? $_POST['fator2']: '';

for ($i = 1; $i <= $fator1; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $fator2;
}

/*
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo $value . ' + ';
}
*/

echo array_sum($arr);
```

Do jeito que esta se eu passar como fator 1 o numero 4 e como fator 2 o numero 5 ele realmente imprime 20 na tela.
Mas o que eu quero imprimir na tela é 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 20.

Mas se eu utilizar o foreach do jeito que esta comentado la em cima ele imprime um sinal de "+" a mais, ele fica 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 20.

Alguém saberia de alguma solução pra esse caso?

Grato!

Comment: Tente assim:

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $valor .=  $value . ' + ';
}
echo substr($valor, 0, -1);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é um caso de *"trailing..."*, podes usar uma função para unir elementos de array com o sinal que escolhes. O [`join`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) ou o [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) fazem isso:

```
<?php

$fator1 = isset($_POST['fator1']) ? $_POST['fator1']: '';
$fator2 = isset($_POST['fator2']) ? $_POST['fator2']: '';

for ($i = 1; $i <= $fator1; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $fator2;
}

echo join(' + ', $arr); 

echo array_sum($arr);

?>
```

Comment: Deu certo @Sergio, muito obrigado. Este join eu não conhecia, vou pesquisar mais sobre

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução possivel:

```
<?php
$num1 = 5;
$num2 = 4;

for($num2; $num2 > 0; $num2--){
    echo $num1;
    if($num2 != 1) echo " + ";
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/i7tLvV)